# Method takes significant amount of time to return values

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, asynchronous

Im dealing with a scenario in C#.net where Im loading a page, and during that pageload event, a service is being called to populate a value which is used to diplay on the page.

The page also has other fields. So the issue here is, the service usually takes between 30 to 60 secs to return the value, other fields cannot be selected until this service returns a value. So there is also a "SAVE" button which cannot be clicked since we are still waiting on this service to return the value.

The problem im trying to solve here is, ideally, on pageload, I want this service to run on the background and let other fields populate the value and I should be able to execute other events like SAVE, NEXT PAGE, PREVIOUS PAGE etc when called.

The purpose of the value returned by the service is for reference only. The code does not have any dependency on this value.

Comment: Is there a asynchronous method you can use to call the service? else create your own?

Comment: Use ' await ' to call an async task

Comment: Are you using ASP.NET? If so, add an ASP.NET tag.

Answer (score 0):

If your service has a method call it by making your onpageload callback async and await the asynchronous method inside of it.

If the service does not have an async method to call you can create your own e.g:

```
public string DownloadStringAsync()
    {
        return "Test data";
    }

    public async Task<string> ReceiveStringAsync()
    {
        return await Task<string>.Run(() =>
        {
            //Method to download your data
            return DownloadStringAsync();
        });
    }
```

and await it in your page load: `sting data = await ReceiveStringAsync();`

You are not providing enough information/code for a better answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can try executing it in a Thread. Something like this

```
    Thread runner = new Thread(() =>
    {
        // run service call here
    });
    runner.IsBackground = true;
    runner.Start();
```

But in C# 4.0 there is the new Task Parallelism Library so you can read about that and proceed from there, technically a Task is like a thread, but the difference is that the Task can have continuation aswell as it manages the Thread pool.

Read TPL here: [Task Parallelism Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460717(v=vs.110).aspx)